# super_search_total_results off when using search: parameter

Tags: solspace, supersearch

I'm using Super Search (2.1.2) as a channel:entries replacement. I'm finding that super_search_total_results is wrong when I use **search:** parameters. A stripped down example:

```
{exp:super_search:results
  channel="files"
  search:files_area="=schedules"
  search:files_type="not digital"
}
```

I *should* have 5 results, but super_search_total_results give me a result of 8, which is the count of *all* items in the files channel, including the digital items. I am seeing only five files (which is right), but the total results result is incorrect.

If I use a query string instead:

```
search&files_area=schedules&files_type=-digital
```

I get 5 items showing and the correct count of 5. I don't always want to put a monstrous query string in the URL if I don't have to, because I don't want someone trying to manipulate it. Also, I don't think I can do an "if empty OR a specific value" in the query string like I can do with this (and will need to do on this site as well):

```
search:files_company="IS_EMPTY|{member_company}"
```

Is there something I'm missing as far as getting the correct total results count when using those search: parameters?

*For anyone coming here with the same issue: I downvoted the initial answer because it doesn't actually answer the question(s).*

I just found this comment in mod.super_search.php on line 1261 (SS v2.1.2):

```
//  If someone uses the search:body="something" template param, the counts 
    can be thrown off. This conditional is a patch that will catch some of the cases.
```

Someone there knows about using the "search:" parameter style, and knows that the counts can be off. I don't think the patch is working, obviously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why this didn't occur to me before, but you can use {absolute_results} inside the Super Search tags. So, the lesson here is, **if you need to use the channel entries style "search:field=" parameter to filter entries (NOT the Super Search "search=" parameter) and you need an accurate number of items returned, use {absolute_results} in place of {super_search_total_results}**.

One trick to note about this is that {super_search_total_results} is available anywhere on the results  template, but {absolute_results} is only available inside the Super Search tags. Depending on how your template is laid out you may have to use Stash to put your {absolute_results} where you need it. (Stash on devot:ee: http://dvt.ee/stash)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for SuperSearch is a little different.
ref http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/results/#search

Something like: search="keywords=green&channel=products&category=pants+shirts&status=-closed&orderby=title+asc&limit=100"

The usage of the "search:" parameter is a current limitation in Super Search. Because Super Search uses the Channel Entries API, it does by default "work" when you try to use "search:stuff" parameters, however Super Search does not account for this in the {super_search_total_results} variable. This is not quite a bug, though I agree it seems like it could be easily supported/added in and be a valuable addition.

Can you submit a Feature Request for it here: http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions/forums/213813

Comment: But then we can't override any of those in the URL if we had to, right? (from the docs: "This method will override any Super Search query through POST as well as any query through the URI.") And how would we do the equivalent of "IS_EMPTY|{member_company}" in the URL, which will be sort of critical on

Comment: It's funny that we can use the "search:" parameter and it will work and filter down to the correct number of returned entries as I'd expect, but it doesn't seem to be supported at all.

Comment: I updated our response above :)